# Modal displays entire json data instead of only one element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

This is how my json looks like. I would like to display the data from the element I clicked on in a modal.

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "companyName": "test",
        "image": "https://mmelektronik.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Insert-logo.jpg.png",
        "location": "Warsaw",
        "salary": "10000",
        "skill": "Junior",
        "tags": "test",
        "jobDescription": "test",
        "title": "UI Designer"
    }

]    

Now I want to access only jobDescription and display it in the modal.
```

```
b-modal(hide-footer="", :id="id")
      template(#modal-title="")
        | Information
      .d-block.text-center
        p {{ want the jobDescription here }}
        b-button(variant="primary") Apply
```

This is how I open the modal.

```
  openModal(item) {
      this.offer = item;
      this.$bvModal.show(this.id);
    }
```

Comment: what is the content of your offers json?

Comment: https://findit-b484b.firebaseio.com/offer.json , instead of displaying only one jobDescription, it displays all of them in the modal. I want, to display jobDescription based on element I clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-for` is used to loop through a set of data, which isn't what you want.  Assuming `id` is the identifier from your `json`, try this:

```html
b-modal(hide-footer="", :id="id")
      template(#modal-title="")
        | Information
      .d-block.text-center
        p() {{ offers[id].jobDescription }}
        b-button(variant="primary") Apply
```

You could put this in a computed instead if you're storing the selected `id` as a data variable:

```js
computed: {
  selected() {
    return this.offers[this.id].jobDescription;
  }
}
```

(Edit:  didn't realize you posted your json, my previous answer was for an array)

Comment: I was about to write, is the json I provided, invalid? Should the json be in an array?I used firebase to create this json for testing purposes. I am waiting for new API, will it work with your answer?

Comment: No it's quite alright, valid json can be either an object or an array.  Array is probably just a bit more commonplace for data sets

Comment: are all those map,filter,reduce etc.. made to be worked on arrays? Should I rework my json to be in array format?

Comment: If your new data is an array of objects, then `offers[id]` will need to be changed, since arrays are looked up by index, not key.  So if it was an array you'd need the index or the array's `.find` method, like you mentioned (yes, those are for arrays).  There is nothing wrong with object data though.  I'd leave it.